# how to build back a splitted and updated string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, for-loop, substitution

With the follwing code I split a string, create a list, and given a specific pattern, substitute a random char with another one

```
comando = "/bin/cat /etc/passwd"
payloadMUT1 = comando
payloadMUT3 = re.split(r'/', payloadMUT1)
filteredarray = []

for i in payloadMUT3:
    #I don't want special chars to get involved in the substitution process
    filteredarray.extend(re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', i))
    
for a in filteredarray:
    
    randomIndex = int(random.random() * len(a))
    randomChar = a[randomIndex]  
    payloadMUT4 = a.replace(randomChar, '?')
```

Output:

```
?in
ca?
et?
pa??wd
```

How do I assemble all those values to build the whole ( updated ) string back?

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
/?in/ca? /et?/pa??wd
```

PS: /bin/cat /etc/passwd is just an example; it could be everything else, also a string with multiple slashes and spaces

Some more examples with complex strings:

```
/bin/find . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \; -> /b?n/fi?d . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \;
/usr/bin/ls | /bin/grep "something" -> /?sr/b?n/l? | /bi?/gre? "something"
/bin/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d "a=a&b=b" -> /?in/cur? http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d "a=a&b=b"
```

Comment: how are this lines stored? in a list of strings? if so you can use `join()`  eg:  `"".join(my_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add another list where to store the modified values (here called 'new_array'), and then using the `join` method to join everything together again

```
comando = '/bin/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d "a=a&b=b"'
new = []


for i in comando.split('/'):
    a = re.search(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', i)
    if a:
        randomIndex = int(random.random() * a.end())
        randomChar = i[randomIndex]  
        new.append(i.replace(randomChar, '?'))
    else:
        new.append(i)

print('/'.join(new))
```

Comment: The space between `cat /etc` isn't conserved

Comment: I modified the answer, basically now i iterate through the original split string rather than filteredarray, and i retain the original special characters that you take out, and then i add an if/else to make sure that the randomization doesn't affect the special characters. It seems to work on the complex strings as well, let me know!

Comment: @Yolao_21 you are almost there, thank you! 
sometimes the substitution is not applied to all the intented parts, for example:

/b?n/cat /?tc/passwd | /?in/grep 'AAAA' -
/bi?/cat /?tc/passwd | /bi?/grep 'AAAA' - 
/b?n/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b' -
/?in/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What would all the intended part be? all the parts of the strings between two " / " that are not special characters? (e.g. only numbers or letters)
For clarification, in the last example, do you want only one substitution in each of these 4 parts? or more than one?
1) bin
2) curl http:
3) 111.111.111.111:1111
4) -X POST -d "a=a&b=b"

Comment: I had to modify your initial code a bit but now it seems to satisfy all the conditions

Comment: @Yolao_21 I really appreciate your help! I get the following results: /bi?/c?rl http://111.111.111.111:1111/?-X?POST?-d?"a=a&b=b" - /?in/cu?l http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -? POST -d "a=a&b=b". Seems like that also the arguments and spaces after the commands get involved in the substituion process. About your question, in the specific case of curl: 1 and 2. But as I pointed, that logic should be for every other commands. With the last update, /bin/cat /etc/passwd | grep "stuff" and /bin/find works fine!

Comment: ok, nvm. i did not notice it happens also with find: /?in/f?nd . -type f -?name "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -? "[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]" {} \; - /?in/?ind . -type ? -iname "*.stu??" -exec egrep -H -i "[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]" {} \; - /bi?/fi?d . -type f -i?ame "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i "[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]" {} \;

Answer (score 1):

You could first split the string by spaces, before splitting on the slash. This way, you can then recombine the paths, before joining them with spaces. However, it does require a few more lines, because of the 2 dimensional array to store each path.

```py
comando = "/bin/cat /etc/passwd"
payloadMUT1 = comando
paths = payloadMUT1.split(' ')
strings = list(map(lambda p: re.split(r'/', p), paths))
print(strings)
filtered_paths = []
new_paths = []
for string_arr in strings:
    #i don't want special chars to get involved in the substitution process
    arr = []
    for string in string_arr:
        if string == '':
            arr.append(string)
            continue    
        arr.extend(re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', string))
    filtered_paths.append(arr)
    
for path_arr in filtered_paths:
    arr = []
    for a in path_arr:
        if a == '':
            arr.append(a)
            continue
        randomIndex = int(random.random() * len(a))
        randomChar = a[randomIndex]  
        payloadMUT4 = a.replace(randomChar, '?')
        arr.append(payloadMUT4)
    new_paths.append(arr)
new_paths = list(map(lambda e: '/'.join(e), new_paths))
print(' '.join(new_paths))
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you for your help! but sadly does not work with complex strings, like the ones i provided. for example: /bin/cat /etc/passwd | /bin/grep 'AAAA' becomes: ->  /bi?/c?t /?tc/p?sswd  /b?n/g?ep ????